# what is the relationship of the isolation level of jdbc and database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have read about 4 levels of isolation of database and know the difference between them.But I don't know what's happen at setting isolation levels by jdbc.
I test on mysql database and its jdbc driver

```
time            Transaction T1(Connection 1)   Transaction T2(Connection 2)
0               set repeatable and print
1                                              set read committed and print
2               print isolation level
3                                              print isolation level


the result:
0              read repeatable
1                                              read committed
2              read repeatable
3                                              read committed
```

We know database adopt different lock strategies according to isolation level,so 
how the mysql process the requests from connections with different isolation level?different connection has different behaviours?

Comment: Isolation level is the property of a transaction, not for the database as a whole.

Comment: so the database adopt different locking strategies based on different transaction?

Comment: As Mark Said Isolation level is the property of a transaction .Here to answer your question JDBC is connector to database .Either in your sql server or whatever server you are using we can set isolation levels or from code using Transaction API we can set the isolation level